# Get the current working directory of process with a pid programmatically on OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, process, applescript, macos-carbon

Is there a way to get the current working directory of a process using it's PID programmatically on OS X?

Cocoa, Carbon, or AppleScript are all acceptable.

It is not acceptable to send "pwd" to the current terminal window/tab (Do not want to affect the workspace).

The linux command "pwdx" also is also unacceptable (just in case you read over the "Cocoa" part)

Answer (score 9):

On 10.5 and later:

`lsof -a -p $PID -d cwd -Fn`

(Prefix with `sudo` if the process is owned by root.)

Answer (score 1):

The following AppleScript is a partial solution for your problem. Given the UNIX pid in the variable `thePID` it first gets the name of the process. It then sends the `do shell script` command to the application process which will result in a child shell process being spawned. The child process inherits the current directory which can then be determined by running the `pwd` command.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theName to name of first process whose unix id is thePID
end tell

tell application theName
    do shell script "/bin/pwd"
end tell
```

The script does not work for processes that do not link to the AppleEvent framework (e.g., pure POSIX processes).